# Как сделать регулярное выражение в javascript для цены с копейками?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я пытаюсь сделать input для ввода цены с копейками c разделителем запятой. Ввод числа в input идет последовательный и если вводимый символ не соответствует то стирается. Но еще пока до конца не разобрался в регулярных выражениях.
Проблема в начале может быть только один 0.
И вторая проблема, запятая может только одна.

```js
$('input').on('input', function() {
   var r = $(this).val();
   r = r.toString().replace(/\./g, ',').replace(/(?=(\d+\,\d{2})),+|(\,(?=\,))|([^\,\d])|(^\D)/gi, '');
   $(this).val(r);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

Готовая функция для форматирования. Подходит для строк и чисел с плавающей точкой. Работает во всех современных браузерах

```
function isString(thing) {
  return typeof thing === 'string';
}

function formatMoney(val) {
  const numberValue = isString(val) ? Number.parseFloat(val) : val;
  return numberValue.toLocaleString('ru', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'rub',
    currencyDisplay: 'symbol',
    maximumFractionDigits: 2,
  });
}
```

Если нужен вариант именно с регуляркой:

```
function formatMoney(data){
  const numberValue = Number.prototype.toFixed.call(parseFloat(data) || 0, 2)           
  return numberValue.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1 ") + ' руб.';
};
```

Comment: У меня идет проверка при вводе  каждого символа на соответствие регулярному выражению. К сожалению этот вариант не подходит.

Comment: Ввод числа в input идет последовательный и если вводимый символ не соответствует то стирается